# How can I provide a custom order shipping value?

Tags: expresso-store, expresso

I'm trying to create a plugin to allow shipping cost based on ranges of post codes. The post codes are hard-coded into the plugin. Due to my lack of experience developing for ExpressionEngine I'm unable to get the plugin to do anything.

Note that the cart only has **one** shipping option; the user shouldn't need to or be able to select a shipping option; this should be applied automatically based on their shipping post code.

Plugin: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/86838c02028faabfb404

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to edit the order directly.

Instead, your extension should implement the `store_order_shipping_methods` hook to return your custom shipping rate, as the official Store shipping extensions do.

Inside the extension file, your hook method should look something like this:

```
public function shipping_methods($order, array $methods)
{
    if (ee()->extensions->last_call !== false) {
        $methods = ee()->extensions->last_call;
    }

    // implement your own shipping logic here
    if ($order->shipping_postcode == '12345') {

        // add a custom shipping method
        $option = new Store\Model\OrderShippingMethod;
        $option->id = 'custom';
        $option->name = 'My Custom Shipping Method';
        $option->amount = 10.00;
        $option->class = __CLASS__;

        $methods[$option->id] = $option;
    }

    return $methods;
}
```

Comment: I'm doing something similar.
Is it okay to override an existing shipping method amount, by specifying an existing $option->id as per your example above?